# For loop with formulas

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have this code below which I want to be used in a loop. However, instead of `C5` and `D5`, I would want this loop to be run on all the cells in column `C` and column `D` and not only for `C5` and `D5`.

To summarize, I would want `C5` and `D5` to be replaced by every cell in Column `C` and `D`. Please assist.

```
For i = 1 To 5
Valuex = Evaluate("=IsNumber(Value(Mid(C5, 2, 1)))")
MsgBox (Valuex)
Valuex1 = Evaluate("=Left(Trim(C5), 1) = ""R""")
MsgBox (Valuex1)

If ((Evaluate("=Left(Trim(C5), 1) = ""R""") = "True") And (Evaluate("=IsNumber(Value(Mid(C5, 2, 1)))") = "True")) Then

Range("D5").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C5,[old.xls]Sheet1!$D:$V,19,0)"
MsgBox ("if")
Else
Range("D5").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C5,[old.xls]Sheet1!$E:$V,18,0)"
MsgBox ("else")
End If
Next i
```

Comment: What purpose does your current loop serve?  What exactly is causing your difficulty as you appear to have a grasp of loops?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question but I want this loop to iterate through all the cells in column C and the if else checks happen in every cell i.e. in every loop iteration

Comment: I was referring to this loop `For i = 1 To 5`.

Comment: Yeah, I put that to try for at least first five cells of column C and then I would have updated it to loop for the entire column.

Comment: I would recommend looking into using `Cells()` instead of `Range()`; and learning more about R1C1 reference style for the formulas.

Comment: However, do you suggest a way where the values fetched from vlookups be pasted special as values and not as formulas. I have tens of thousands of cells with formulas (due to vlookups) which is only slowing and lagging excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this does what you want. It will run from row 1 to the last row in C. Note that you could do all this without VBA.

```
Sub x()

Dim i As Long, Valuex As Boolean, Valuex1 As Boolean

For i = 1 To Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Valuex = Evaluate("=IsNumber(Value(Mid(C" & i & ", 2, 1)))")
    MsgBox (Valuex)
    Valuex1 = Evaluate("=Left(Trim(C" & i & "), 1) = ""R""")
    MsgBox (Valuex1)
    If Valuex1 And Valuex Then
        Range("D" & i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C" & i & ",[old.xls]Sheet1!$D:$V,19,0)"
        MsgBox ("if")
    Else
        Range("D" & i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C" & i & ",[old.xls]Sheet1!$E:$V,18,0)"
        MsgBox ("else")
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I think you can avoid the loop altogether thus

```
Sub xx()

Dim i As Long

i = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("D1:D" & i)
    .Formula = "=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(C1, 2, 1))),LEFT(TRIM(C1), 1) = ""R""),VLOOKUP(C1,Sheet1!$D:$V,19,0),VLOOKUP(C1,Sheet1!$E:$V,18,0))"
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It Worked!! :) That was amazing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: However, do you suggest a way where the values fetched from vlookups be pasted special as values and not as formulas. I have tens of thousands of cells with formulas (due to vlookups) which is only slowing and lagging excel.

Comment: I've amended the second bit of code to overwrite the formulae with values.

Comment: Worked very well. You are brilliant!!